# ¿Como sumar 2 dias a una fecha?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, vb

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Deseo sumar 2 días a la fecha actual por SQL Server o vb.net, pero el problema es que al sumarle los días deba ser considerado hasta las 20:00pm.

Por Ejemplo si la fecha es 27-07-2021 03:00 am y le sumo 2 días debería ser 29-07-2021 03:00 pero debería ser máximo hasta 20:00pm entonces debería ser hasta 28-07-2021 20:00pm

```
SELECT dateadd(day,2,getdate())
```

Es posible condicionar esa forma de sumar días.

Se puede manejar por sql server o por vb.net cual pueda acercarse a la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función DateAdd no permite hacer eso que necesitas. La única solución posible es que después de añadir los 2 días, tengas un IF que verifique si la hora es mayor de lo que necesitas la establezca al valor necesario.